# Show $f(x)=x\sec(x)$ is one-to-one on$\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, inverse-function

So as the title states I have to show that the above function $f(x)=x\sec(x)$
is one-to-one on the interval $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

However, i'm not entirely sure how without testing every number between the given interval?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You might show that the derivative is strictly positive

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{d}{dx} x\sec(x) = (x\tan(x)+1)\sec(x) > 0 $ on the given interval.

Comment: How do you know the derivative always will be larger than 0?

Comment: It's obvious that $sec(x) > 0$ on the given interval, so we can reduce it without any danger. Then $x*tan(x) ≥ 0$, because if $x$ is negative, then $tan(x)$ is negative and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Computing the derivative of your function, we find
$$
f'(x)=\frac{\cos x+x\sin x}{\cos^2 x}
$$
which vanishes whenever
$$
-x=\tan x
$$
which by inspection occurs when $x=0$, and nowhere else, since 
$$
(\tan x+x)'=\sec^2x+1>0
$$ 
So we test on either side of $0$, the only place we could have the problem of $f'$ changing signs, for positive $x$, that $f'>0$ is clear. We check the convenient value $x=-\pi/4$ on the left to find
$$
\cos(\pi/4)-\pi/4\sin(\pi/4)=\sqrt{2}/2(1-\frac{\pi}{4})>0
$$
so yes, it is indeed invertible.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\frac{x}{\cos x}$ is an odd function and $\lim_{x\to \left(\pm\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{\mp}}f(x)=\pm\infty$, $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$. $f(x)$ is positive on $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ and over such interval $\log f(x) = \log(x)-\log(\cos x)$ is increasing, since $\frac{d}{dx}\log f(x)$ equals $\frac{1}{x}+\tan(x)>0$. It follows that $f(x)$ is increasing over $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

Comment: Thank you. It helped a little but i'm not really sure why you use lograthims?

Comment: @oxodo: if $f(x)$ is positive, $f(x)$ is increasing iff $\log f(x)$ is increasing, and it is simpler to compute $\frac{d}{dx}\log f(x)$ rather than $\frac{d}{dx}\,f(x)$, since $f(x)$ is given by a ratio of simple functions.

Answer (score 0):

Because $\cos x$ is strictly decreasing and nonnegative on $[0,\pi/2),$ $\sec x = 1/\cos x$ is strictly increasing and nonnegative on $[0,\pi/2).$ The function $x$ is also strictly increasing and nonnegative on $[0,\pi/2).$ Therefore the product $x\sec x$ is strictly increasing and nonnegative on $[0,\pi/2).$

Now any odd fuction on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ that is strictly increasing on $[0,\pi/2)$ is strictly increasing on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2).$ Since $x\sec x$ is odd, we have the desired result.

Comment: Thank you. It helped, I got some questions though. 
1. "Now any odd fuction on $(π/2,π/2)$" did you mean $(-π/2,π/2)$?
2. How does an odd function imply that the it will be stricly increasing on the interval $(-π/2,π/2)$? I get that $f(-x)=-y$ for an oddfunction, but i'm a little lost on the details. Thank you btw.

Comment: 1. Thanks, that was a typo.  2. I didn't say that. I said "any odd fuction on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ **that is strictly increasing on $[0,\pi/2)$** is strictly increasing on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2).$"

Comment: Right. But how does "any odd fuction on $(−π/2,π/2)(−π/2,π/2)$ that is strictly increasing on $[0,π/2)[0,π/2)$" imply that the same function will be increasing on $(−π/2,π/2)$?